# i use jquery can't get html p element text

Tags: jquery

Below is html on my page, i want to get item price if the price exist.

```
    <ol id="ordered">
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#1</span>
           <p class="price">$22.99</p>
      </li>
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#2</span>
           <p>no price</p>
      </li>
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#3</span>
           <p class="price">$13.19</p>
      </li>
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#4</span>
           <p>no price</p>
    
     </li>
     <li class="itemnew">
         <span>#5</span>
         <p class="price">$22.79</p>
     </li>
    </ol>
```

I want result as follow:

## 1

$22.99

## 2

no price

## 3

$13.19

## 4

no price

## 5

$22.79

my code is here, but can't work.

```
    var numli = $('ol#ordered li');

    var rank=[];
    var price=[];

    for(var i=0;i<numli.length;i++){
        rank[i]=$(numli[i])has( "span" ).text();
        if($(numli[i]).has( "<p class="price">" )) {price[i]=$(numli[i]).has( "<p class="price">" ).text();}
    else{price[i]='no price';}
        
    }
```

Comment: I need results as this: #1 $22.99 #2 no price #3 $13.19 #4 no price #5 $22.79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item = $('.itemnew');
var ptext = "";
item.each(function(){   
    ptext = $(this).children('span').text();
    if($(this).children('price').length){
        ptext  = ptext + $(this).children('price').text();      
    }
});

console.log(ptext);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per discussed in the comment, updated to work while not changing the HTML structure, simply target the `<p>` tag instead of the `.price` class :

```
function getPrices(){
    var priceString = '';
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('itemnew')).map(function(item, index) {
        priceString += index + '' + item.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
    });

    return priceString;
};

var prices = getPrices();
console.log(prices);
```

Can't say for the Jquery code, but this vanilla JS would do the thing:

1.give all price elements the class of `.price`, regardless of their content.

```
<ol id="ordered">
  <li class="itemnew">
       <span>#1</span>
       <p class="price">$22.99</p>
  </li>
  <li class="itemnew">
       <span>#2</span>
       <p class="price">no price</p>
  </li>
  <li class="itemnew">
       <span>#3</span>
       <p class="price">$13.19</p>
  </li>
  <li class="itemnew">
       <span>#4</span>
       <p class="price">no price</p>

 </li>
 <li class="itemnew">
     <span>#5</span>
     <p class="price">$22.79</p>
 </li>
</ol>
```

2.Then iterate the values :

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('itemnew')).map(function(item, index) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(item.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML);
});
```

3.Or, as you comment requested to show them all in a single string:

```
function getPrices(){
    var priceString = '';
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('itemnew')).map(function(item, index) {
        priceString += index + '' + item.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML;
    });

    return priceString;
};

var prices = getPrices();
console.log(prices);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the page html structure can't change.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple code :

```
var price = $('p');
price.each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('price')){
    console.log($(this).html());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, if the html structure like this: <ol id="ordered">
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#1</span>
           <p class="price">$22.99</p>
      </li>
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#2</span>
           <span>no price</span>
      </li>
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#3</span>
           <p class="price">$13.19</p>
      </li>
      <li class="itemnew">
           <span>#4</span>
           <span>no price</span>

     </li>
     <li class="itemnew">
         <span>#5</span>
         <p class="price">$22.79</p>
     </li>
    </ol>

Comment: Can't undertand ? Can you explain it.